# Julia 1.4: can't install any packages due to unrecognized URL prefix

Tags: git, proxy, julia

I'm trying to install package in julia 1.4.2 but it always returns this:

```
(@v1.4) pkg> add Gadfly
    Cloning default registries into `~/.julia`
    Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Net, unrecognized URL prefix)
```

If I try using `Pkg.add()`, then it's like this

```
julia> Pkg.add("Gadfly")
    Cloning default registries into `~/.julia`
    Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Net, unrecognized URL prefix)
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:53
 [2] clone(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::String, ::String; header::String, credentials::Nothing, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/GitTools.jl:151
 [3] (::Pkg.Types.var"#89#92"{Pkg.Types.Context,String,Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec})(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:939
 [4] mktempdir(::Pkg.Types.var"#89#92"{Pkg.Types.Context,String,Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec}, ::String; prefix::String) at ./file.jl:682
 [5] mktempdir at ./file.jl:680 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [6] clone_or_cp_registries(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec,1}, ::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:920
 [7] clone_or_cp_registries at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:911 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [8] clone_default_registries(::Pkg.Types.Context) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:829
 [9] find_registered!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:1176
 [10] registry_resolve!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:735
 [11] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:146
 [12] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:112
 [13] #add#27 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:109 [inlined]
 [14] add at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:109 [inlined]
 [15] #add#24 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:107 [inlined]
 [16] add at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:107 [inlined]
 [17] add(::String; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:106
 [18] add(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:106
 [19] top-level scope at REPL[5]:1
caused by [exception 1]
GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Net, unrecognized URL prefix)
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/LibGit2/src/error.jl:101 [inlined]
 [2] clone(::SubString{String}, ::String, ::LibGit2.CloneOptions) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/LibGit2/src/repository.jl:459
 [3] clone(::SubString{String}, ::String; branch::String, isbare::Bool, remote_cb::Ptr{Nothing}, credentials::LibGit2.CachedCredentials, callbacks::Dict{Symbol,Tuple{Ptr{Nothing},Any}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/LibGit2/src/LibGit2.jl:580
 [4] clone(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::String, ::String; header::String, credentials::Nothing, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/GitTools.jl:143
 [5] (::Pkg.Types.var"#89#92"{Pkg.Types.Context,String,Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec})(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:939
 [6] mktempdir(::Pkg.Types.var"#89#92"{Pkg.Types.Context,String,Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec}, ::String; prefix::String) at ./file.jl:682
 [7] mktempdir at ./file.jl:680 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [8] clone_or_cp_registries(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.RegistrySpec,1}, ::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:920
 [9] clone_or_cp_registries at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:911 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [10] clone_default_registries(::Pkg.Types.Context) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:829
 [11] find_registered!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:1176
 [12] registry_resolve!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Types.jl:735
 [13] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:146
 [14] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:112
 [15] #add#27 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:109 [inlined]
 [16] add at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:109 [inlined]
 [17] #add#24 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:107 [inlined]
 [18] add at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:107 [inlined]
 [19] add(::String; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/API.jl:106
 [20] add(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/shar
```

My desktop is Ubuntu 18.04, though I always have my proxy on (socks5), I tried to disable it, or enable it, or enable it and enter julia with `proxychains julia`, but none of these work.

I previous installed julia 1.2 and had my previous packages (not working either) installed in `~/.julia`. I also tried to `mv .julia .julia_` but did work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `mv .gitconfig .gitconfig_` provided by @Negrito, it did solve the downloading problem, however, after downloading, it returns the error of:

`(@v1.4) pkg> add Gadfly Resolving package versions... Downloading artifact: IntelOpenMP curl: (7) Failed to receive SOCKS4 connect request ack. ERROR: Unable to automatically install 'IntelOpenMP' from '/home/kuai/.julia/packages/IntelOpenMP_jll/hsAKN/Artifacts.toml'` 
More over, `git clone` outside julia doesn't work since the proxy is on. After searching the internet, the [solution](http://(@v1.4)%20pkg%3E%20add%20Gadfly%20%20%20Resolving%20package%20versions...%20Downloading%20artifact:%20IntelOpenMP%20curl:%20(7)%20Failed%20to%20receive%20SOCKS4%20connect%20request%20ack.%20ERROR:%20Unable%20to%20automatically%20install%20%27IntelOpenMP%27%20from%20%27/home/kuai/.julia/packages/IntelOpenMP_jll/hsAKN/Artifacts.toml%27) is to add

`ENV["HTTP_PROXY"] = "socks5://127.0.0.1:port_number"`

`ENV["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "socks5://127.0.0.1:port_number"`

in the `/opt/julia-1.4.2/etc/julia/startup.jl` (path maybe different, use `locate startup.jl` to find).

Answer (score 2):

This probably due to the `~/.gitconfig` proxy issue discussed on [github](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/33111), so try `mv .gitconfig .gitconfig_` to see if it works.